# McDowell's World Building Mandala

Tags: world-building

**Does anyone have an outline or template for McDowell's World Building Mandala?**

I came across it in an [article](https://onezero.medium.com/nike-and-boeing-are-paying-sci-fi-writers-to-predict-their-futures-fdc4b6165fa4) about Scifi writers being paid as futurologists, but this is all they said, "The labels Mind, Body, Self, and Fuel are clustered in the center. They branch out to Governance, Structure, Culture, and Energy and represent a method of organizing data about how an individual is situated in a given world."
[[image: The mandala of the holistic World2]

Comment: Have you tried a Google search because I just found what appears to be a free manual on using said mandala.

Comment: Yes, I went through at least one page of results, both in the text and image searches. Even getting a clear image has been problematic.

Answer (score 2):

No such document is accessible online, the mandala is actually a propitiatory tool that is used by McDowell's World Building Media Lab and 5D Global Studio. I did find a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tf-Zmq1S56Y) of his presentation of the technique as applied to *[Minority Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_Report_(film))* that may or may not be useful to you.